# Title in navbar crashing because of a message being sent to a deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have the following code in `viewDidLoad` (to set a title in the nav bar) that's crashing with a "message sent to deallocated instance" error:

```
UILabel * label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,45,45)] autorelease];

label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Mayfield Regular" size:15];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;

label.text=@"SEARCH"; //CUSTOM TITLE
[label sizeToFit];
[label release];
```

How can I go about correcting this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Remove the `autorelease` or the `[label release]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overreleasing the label. You call `autorelease` in the first line you posted and then you also call `release` in the last line you posted. Only do one of these.

Comment: i see that now. it's an old project and just doing some minor changes to it. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
UILabel * label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,45,45)] autorelease];
```

and than release

```
[label release];
```

This is clearly wrong. You either go with the autorelease or with the release.